# how to use function keys and keywords at the same time in c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, winappdriver

Have to press f7Q to quit from an windows application for that my below code is not working.

```
element.SendKeys(Keys.F7 + "Q");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you correctly, you want to send a key combination to the browser/driver. If that is the case, you can use Actions. Example code below:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(Keys.F7 + "Q");
```